# Testing a MassTransit Consumer using the InMemoryTestFixture

Tags: unit-testing, masstransit

Wanting to design my test around a MassTransit Consumer where i can send the consumers messages with a variety of content. Base on the content of the message the consumer will "do work" and relay a messages.

The problem i have is when running two of these test, in separate test fixtures,  there seems to be something interfering with the second test. But run individually each test runs successfully.

After looking through the MassTransit Test project i have come up with some example test code to demonstrate the problem i'm having.

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class PingPongMessageTestFixture : InMemoryTestFixture
{
    private PongConsumer _pongConsumer;
    protected override void ConfigureInMemoryReceiveEndpoint(IInMemoryReceiveEndpointConfigurator configurator)
    {
        _received = Handled<IPongMessage>(configurator);
    }

    protected override void PreCreateBus(IInMemoryBusFactoryConfigurator configurator)
    {
        var _pingConsumer = new PingConsumer();
        _pongConsumer = new PongConsumer();
        configurator.ReceiveEndpoint("test_ping_queue", e =>
        {
            e.Consumer(() => _pingConsumer);
        });

        configurator.ReceiveEndpoint("test_pong_queue", e =>
        {
            e.Consumer(() => _pongConsumer);
        });
    }

    Task<ConsumeContext<IPongMessage>> _received;

    [Test]
    public async Task test_how_to_test_consumers()
    {
        await Bus.Publish<IPingMessage>(new { MessageId = 100 });
        await _received;

        Assert.IsTrue(_pongConsumer.hitme);
        Assert.AreEqual(100, _pongConsumer.pongMessage.MessageId);
    }

    public class PingConsumer : IConsumer<IPingMessage>
    {
        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IPingMessage> context)
        {
            context.Publish<IPongMessage>(new { context.Message.MessageId });
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

    public class PongConsumer : IConsumer<IPongMessage>
    {
        internal bool hitme;
        internal IPongMessage pongMessage;
        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IPongMessage> context)
        {
            hitme = true;
            pongMessage = context.Message;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

    public interface IPingMessage
    {
        int MessageId { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IPongMessage
    {
        int MessageId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

this test will send a message to the ping consumer which itself will send a message to the pong consumer.

This by itself works and tests that the ping consumer will send a pong message. In a real life scenario the "ping" consumer to send Update messages to another service and the pong consumer is just a test consumer used with the tests.

If i have a second test fixture, which for this questions is very similar, it will fail when both test are run together. though individually it will pass.

The test does the same thing

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class DingDongMessageTestFixture : InMemoryTestFixture
{
    private DongConsumer _pongConsumer;
    protected override void ConfigureInMemoryReceiveEndpoint(IInMemoryReceiveEndpointConfigurator configurator)
    {
        _received = Handled<IDongMessage>(configurator);
    }

    protected override void PreCreateBus(IInMemoryBusFactoryConfigurator configurator)
    {
        var _dingConsumer = new DingConsumer();
        _dongConsumer = new DongConsumer();
        configurator.ReceiveEndpoint("test_ding_queue", e =>
        {
            e.Consumer(() => _dingConsumer);
        });

        configurator.ReceiveEndpoint("test_dong_queue", e =>
        {
            e.Consumer(() => _dongConsumer);
        });
    }

    Task<ConsumeContext<IDongMessage>> _received;

    [Test]
    public async Task test_how_to_test_consumers()
    {
        await Bus.Publish<IDingMessage>(new { MessageId = 100 });
        await _received;

        Assert.IsTrue(_pongConsumer.hitme);
        Assert.AreEqual(100, _pongConsumer.pongMessage.MessageId);
    }

    public class DingConsumer : IConsumer<IDingMessage>
    {
        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IDingMessage> context)
        {
            context.Publish<IDongMessage>(new { context.Message.MessageId });
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

    public class DongConsumer : IConsumer<IDongMessage>
    {
        internal bool hitme;
        internal IDongMessage pongMessage;
        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IDongMessage> context)
        {
            hitme = true;
            pongMessage = context.Message;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

    public interface IDingMessage
    {
        int MessageId { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IDongMessage
    {
        int MessageId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Is this a good approach for testing a Masstransit consumers?

If so, do i need to reset the InMemoryTestFixture, somehow, per test fixture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your test fixtures, I don't believe there should be any conflict, but because of the interaction with NUnit, there may be something of which I'm unaware because of the base class inheritance that's being used.

If you use the `InMemoryTestHarness` directly (the same functionality as the text fixtures, but without any testing framework dependency) I would expect that you should not experience any interactions between two simultaneously executing tests.

Your approach is the way it should be done, but again, I'd suggesting using the `InMemoryTestHarness` instead of the fixture.

An example test is linked: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/master/src/MassTransit.Tests/Testing/ConsumerTest_Specs.cs

Comment: How would you hook up a consumer to the test harness that doesn't have a parameterless constructor?

Comment: this works for me  _consumer = _harness.Consumer(() => { return (PingConsumer)pingConsumer; });

Comment: Nice answer! This should be in the documentation somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The key to this behaviour lies in the [source code](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit.TestFramework/InMemoryTestFixture.cs) for the `InMemoryTestFixture`.

```
public class InMemoryTestFixture : BusTestFixture
{

    ...

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public Task SetupInMemoryTestFixture()
    {
        return InMemoryTestHarness.Start();
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public async Task TearDownInMemoryTestFixture()
    {
        await InMemoryTestHarness.Stop().ConfigureAwait(false);

        InMemoryTestHarness.Dispose();
    }

    ...

}
```

As you can see from this snippet, the test harness is started and stopped in `[OneTimeSetUp]` and `[OneTimeTearDown]` tags, i.e before any tests in the `[TestFixture]` are run and after all tests in the fixture are complete - **not** for each test case.

My solution is to create a new test fixture each time. I believe this is what the writers of `MassTransit.TestFramework` intended as it is what they do in their [`Common_SagaStateMachine` example](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/tests/MassTransit.Containers.Tests/Common_Tests/Common_SagaStateMachine.cs).